# Redux, when to split reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a Redux store with a reducer consisting of 9 case statements. Six of these cases deal with populating an array in the state white three deal with sorting said array, thus there is no natural way of splitting the reducer, is it ok to leave the reducer as one?

Answer (score 1):

The number of case statements isn't the right metric for deciding whether you should split your reducer. Rather, it's ***how deeply nested is the state slice that your reducer action handler is working on***. If its too deep, the code could explode.

Lets say you have this state shape:

```
{
  cart: {
    products: [ {name:"shirt"}, {name:"pants"} ],
    checkout: false,
  }
}
```

---

In a single/global reducer setup, you might have this action handler:

```js
//reducer.js
case ADD_CART_PRODUCT:
  const {newProduct} = payload
  const {cart: {products}} = state

  return {...state, cart: {...state.cart, products: [...products, newProduct] } }
```

---

Not bad, but you can split off a `cartReducer` for action handlers that affects the `cart` state slice, shrinking your code to this:

```js
//cartReducer.js
case ADD_CART_PRODUCT:
  const {newProduct} = payload
  const {products} = state //this is actually state.cart from the global perspective

  return {...state, products: [...products, newProduct] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is okay to leave the reducer as one.  Lets say if I have a reducer for User, I would consider splitting the reducer if it got too big to manage or if it had nothing to do with User and that was my first one.  You only have 9 switch cases and that should be fine.